# Connecting CN3722 to Load AND Battery

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, wiring, solar-charge-controller

Like the title says, can I do this? I got two schematics in mind about how to wire these up, which  one is the correct one?

This one is straightforward, but will it actually work if connected to load?
[image: Schematic 1, Straightforward]

I think this one will interfere with the MPPT of CN3722, but I am not sure
[image: Schematic 2, With Diodes]

The CN3722 and XL4015 in the schematics are in module form not bare ic, but these are the datasheets:

http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/datasheet/DSE-CN3722.pdf
https://www.elecrow.com/download/XL4015_datasheet.pdf

Comment: More info would be nice, like links to datasheets for both IC's and what you actually intend to do.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot, the question has been updated with datasheets links and additional explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing an MPPT controller with a diode is not a good idea, because when the diode is conducting current, it will create problems for the MPPT controller and it's power calculation.

It would be better to have a separate MPPT and BMS

The other problem is the DC/DC converter's doesn't have a cutoff, and stops at 4V so the cells will be overdrawn (and die) if there isn't any logic to shut the DC DC converter off.

Comment: The Li-ions are in 3S so it has the range of 12.6v when full and 9v when empty.

Also you are right I forgot the BMS there.

Comment: This is a bit old, so sorry for reviving an old thead. From this answer, it is not clear to me is the first circuit the OP presented is valid. I would like to mount something similar, but after thinking a bit about the first circuit, I think it would be charging/discharging the battery constantly, even when the solar panel can provide power for the load, as the CN3722 will cut when the battery is charged, and therefore there will be no flow from the solar panel to the load, no? How should we add a load to the CN3722?