# Connect load directly to battery pack and to a CN3722 board

Tags: battery-charging, 18650

So first of all, there is this question in this same site, but I think it has not been totally answered.

[Connecting CN3722 to Load AND Battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543932/connecting-cn3722-to-load-and-battery)

[image]

My question is the same, can I connect a load to a battery which is connected to a CN3722 charger controller, like shown in the figure? Of course, the battery has its own BMS, so the load and the charger are not connected directly to the 18650 cells, but to the BMS. Do I need a diode for preventing reverse flow between the battery and the CN3722 charger? Is it safe to use the load while the battery is being charged?